# How can I perform an async operation in $.Deferred.then failFilter callback and pass back to success chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

the following will pass flow back to success chain after handling error:

```
asyncThatWillFail().then(null, function () {
    //handle error
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
}).then(nextSuccessCallback);
```

In my particular scenario though, I need to perform multiple parallel async operations in the error handler using the `$.when.apply($, promises)` approach:

```
asyncThatWillFail().then(null, function () {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 1000);
        promises.push(dfd.promise());
    }
    return $.when.apply($,promises);
}).then(nextSuccessCallback);
```

I had assumed the above would work since I am returning promise that would eventually be resolved. This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9ca3fa4/) though shows that after going through my error handler, neither the following success or error callback are called.

Since the action in the error handler is async, I can't just go ahead and send some resolved value through the return. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The promise thing would work, but you have only one `dfd` variable that you are resolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue now is closure ... only the last created promise in the loop of 3 will be resolved due to closure

```
asyncThatWillFail().then(null, function () {
    log("error handler");
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        (function() { // IIFE for a closure
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            setTimeout(function () {
                dfd.resolve();
            }, 1000);
            promises.push(dfd.promise());
        }());
    }
    return $.when.apply(null,promises);
}).then(nextSuccessCallback, nextFailCallback);

function asyncThatWillFail () {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function(){
      dfd.reject();
  }, 1000)
  return dfd.promise();
}

function nextSuccessCallback () {
    log("success");
}

function nextFailCallback () {
  log("failure");
}

function log (msg) {
    $("#logger").append("<p>"+msg+"</p>");
}
```

see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9ca3fa4/2/)

Comment: ah forgot about that... wish I could use ES6 `let` in the browser